# In Excel How can I prevent the user from leaving a blank cell in Excel's cell "A1"?

Tags: excel

Using data validation, I constructed a dropdown list in cell "A1" in Excel that says "Yes" and "No."

What I want is for the user to select "Yes" or "No" in cell "A1." It should not be left blank; instead, it should alert us that "cell A1 should not be blank."

What is the best way to do this in Excel? Could someone please assist me?

Comment: When exactly should the user be notified? When saving the file? Or navigating to another tab? Or some other trigger? What type of notification? Some more detail would be helpful.

Comment: @BigBen, It should alert while navigating to another tab. Notification could be a warning message  saying ""cell A1 should not be left blank"

Comment: Research the [Worksheet.Deactivate event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.deactivate) (VBA) perhaps.

Answer (score 2):

In B1, put the formula:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A1),"      Must enter a choice","      OK")
```

(The spaces allow room for the Data Validation dropdown arrow.)